# mac terminal error not a valid identifier while running NDK

Tags: android, macos, shell, android-ndk, terminal

I am trying to run these commands in my mac terminal but it gives error `bashrc is not a valid identifier` every time i run these commands.

```
NDK_HOME=/path/to/your/ndk_installation
export PATH=$NDK_HOME:$PATH to ~/.bashrc
```

Please help me figure out why I'm not able to run these commands.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you are following seem to be telling you to edit the file `~/.bashrc` (where ~ is your home directory, so `/Users/<your login name>/.bashrc` on OSX) and add the lines:

```
NDK_HOME=/path/to/your/ndk_installation
export PATH="$NDK_HOME:$PATH"
```

You should replace `/path/to/your/ndk_installation` with the directory where you have unpacked the NDK.

The purpose of this is to add the NDK directory to the search path, so you can easily run commands like `ndkbuild` at the command line.  The `.bashrc` file is run by your shell (bash) every time you start it, so adding these lines there ensure the NDK is always in your path.